# Submitting a form with a param to new controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

```
Rails 6
bootstrap 4
```

In my books_controller.rb, I have:

```
def index
  @books = Book.select(:id, :name)
end

def new
    @book = Book.new
  end

def create
  @book = Book.new(book_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @book.save
      format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @book }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I have a table, in my views/books/index.htmlslim, I have:

```
table.table.table-striped
  thead
    tr
      th Name
  tbody
    - @books.each do |book|
      tr
        td = book.name
```

What I would like to do, is at the end of the table, add a form, allowing users to add a book, without going to a separate form, something like:

I tried:

```
= form_with url: new_book_path do |f|
  .form-inputs
    = f.label 'Add Book'
    = f.text_field :book_name
  .form-actions
    = f.submit
```

And I also tried:

```
= simple_form_for(@book) do |f|
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :book_name
```

But nothing happens, when I click on submit, and I get the following message:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/bookd/new"):
```

I also tried:

```
= simple_form_for(@book || Book.new) do |f|
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :book_name
```

But. I am getting a:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `book_name` for #<Book:0x000007f9cce...>);
```

One other thought, is to make it a link, something like:

```
= link_to new_book_path, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-lg"
```

But how do I pass the book_name parameter, and which controller action should it go to?

Here are my routes:

```
books GET /books(.:format) books#index
POST /books(.:format) books#create
new_book GET /books/new(.:format) books#new
edit_book GET /books/:id/edit(.:format) books#edit
book GET /books/:id(.:format) books#show
PATCH /books/:id(.:format) books#update
PUT /books/:id(.:format) books#update
DELETE /books/:id(.:format) books#destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails you don't create resources by posting to the `new` route- you post to the collection route eg. `/books`. The new action is just used to create a page with a form on it.

Its still really puzzling why `new_book_path` would return `/bookd/new` but the error is actually correct. `new_book_path` responds to GET - not POST. This is explained in [Rails Routing from the Outside](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).

If you actually just use:

```
table.table.table-striped
  thead
    tr
      th Name
  tbody
    - @books.each do |book|
      tr
        td = book.name

= simple_form_for(@book || Book.new) do |f|
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name # book_name is a typo?
```

It will correctly create a form with `action="/books" method="POST"`.

I have no idea what your trying to do with this mess:

```
= form_with url: new_book_path do |f|
  .form-inputs
    = f.label 'Add Book'
    = f.text_field :book_name
  .form-actions
    = f.submit    

    = simple_form_for(@book) do |f|
      .form-inputs
        = f.input :book_name
```

But none of [the HTML specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html)  allow nested `<form>` elements and the results can be wildly unpredictable. For example a submit button may submit the inner form or the outer form.

Comment: Sorry, this is a copy/paste error. I was trying to post the two DIFFERENT ways I approached it, they're not both used simultaneously

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and I am getting an: undefined method `book_name' for #<Book:0x00007f9cce85a8a0> error

Comment: That means that you don't have a `book_name` column in the books table. Either its a typo and you mean `= f.text_field :name` or you have not created or run the migration that adds the column to the model. I would guess the former based on your table.

Comment: Yes, I had changed the name, and had not fixed it. It's working now, but the return is to activate the Show book view, so I will need to do some additional work, so I can land back on the Index view